# Does a single quote break a Power BI relationship?

Tags: powerbi

There is a relationship on player name in my Power BI visualization. One of the names (Franck Songo'o) has a single quote that I think may be causing the relationship to fail. The failure is his image not loading based on a goals scored table. The name is the link between the goals and image table.

Do single quotes break relationships? Is there away around this?

The visualization, https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiZjI1ZGI2ZDYtNjkyNS00ZjBiLWJmOTctNjQ0NzEzNDk3ZWU5IiwidCI6IjA4ZGU4NjI4LTU5M2UtNDNmNS05Y2ViLWYzZTVkZDdhZTJjYiIsImMiOjF9